# Q: Packet sniffer in python using include pcapy

Tags: python, windows, include

my OS ist Win 7 32 Bit.
I would like to install pyapy, unfortunately it doesn't work.
What do I have to do so that "include pycapy" accesses c: \ sulley_build \ Lib \ site \ site-packages \ pcapy.pyd?

I got the installer
pcapy-0.10.5.win32-py2.5-winpcap4.1.2.msi
of
https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/quickpost-updated-impacketpcapy-installers-for-python-2-5-2-6-2-7/

Unfortunately without success:

`C:\sulley_build\sulley>python network_monitor.py`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "network_monitor.py", line 7, in <module>`

`import pcapy`

`ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.`

`C:\sulley_build\sulley>`

and

`#!c:\\python\\python.exe`

`import threading`

`import getopt`

`import time`

`import sys`

`import os`

`import pcapy <----Line 7`

`import impacket`

`---Schnipp----`

Answer (score 0):

does nobody have an idea?
i am grateful for every approach